# What are the options to "atomically" stage different files (not having ZFS)

Tags: backup, synchronization, sqlite

I need to take a backup of an SQLite3 DB matching the state of other applications writing to disk, besides a [vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/storage/filesystem.html) using the filesystem as a backend.

I need to do this in a system with no [ZFS](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/zfs.html) so [no snapshots](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gbcya/index.html) could be taken.

Currently trying a basic script with something like this:

```
DAY=$(date +%d)

TDIR=$(mktemp -d)
cleanup() {
    test -n "${TDIR}" && test -d "${TDIR}" && rm -rf "${TDIR}"
}
trap cleanup EXIT

# define and create the working directory
WRKDIR="${TDIR}/${DAY}"
mkdir "${WRKDIR}"

# take dump of the sqlite db
sqlite3 /data/data/test.db ".backup '${WRKDIR}/test.db'"

# backup the vault keys
cp -R /data/vault/ ${WRKDIR}/vault

# backup logs
cp -R /data/logs/ ${WRKDIR}/logs
```